# When i Click Enter multiple times then Record created multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click Entyer multiple times the record creates multiple times

```
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        debugger;
        // Create receipt on press key enter
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("input[id='BtnCreate'").focus().click();
            return false;

        }
        // Go back the previous page on press esc key
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            var url = $("#btnCancel").attr("href");
            window.location = url;
            return false;
        }

    });
},
```

Comment: You need a logic to disable/enable the button.
You may need to send an Ajax call to know whether current record already exist, then disable/enable your BtnCreate.
Another solution is to send the request anyway, and in your backend service, insert if not exist, update if already exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        debugger;
        // Create receipt on press key enter
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("input[id='BtnCreate'").focus().click();
            $('#BtnCreate').off();
            return false;
        }
        // Go back the previous page on press esc key
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            var url = $("#btnCancel").attr("href");
            window.location = url;
            return false;
        }

    });
},
```

Comment: Or you can use $('#BtnCreate').diabled=true; to disable the button to avoid multiple submission.